# How to check if solution to NSolve exists?

Tags: equation-solving, conditional, logic

I'm trying to created a table where the entries are values of x, either given by x/.NSolve[...][[1]] or a fixed value x0 if there is no numerical solution. Is there a way to find the truth value for whether a solution to the NSolve exists (to be used in an If statement)?

Comment: What sort of equations? Are they guaranteed always to produce either zero or exactly one solution?

Answer (score 1):

Easier than `If`, I think, just to use rewriting, *Mathematica*'s strength:

```
NSolve[x^2 == 1] /. {} -> x0 /. {{x -> soln_}, ___} -> soln
```

This replaces an empty solution set `{}` with x0, and a non-empty set with the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

A computationally fast way is to use `Exists` and `Resolve`. For instance, maybe you wanted to determine if there are real solutions to $x^2=1$. You could do:

```
Exists[x, x^2==1]
```

And then:

```
Resolve[%, Reals]
```